# How to I access View Controllers from App Delegate (XCode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I have a storyboard with a split view. When the app starts I want to set the model for the view.

I have a simple class Day:

```
import Foundation

class Day: NSObject{
    var date: Date
    var sleep: Double
    init(date: Date, sleep: Double){
        self.date = date
        self.sleep = sleep
        super.init()
    }
    override convenience init(){
        self.init(date: Date(), sleep: 8.0)
    }
}
```

I have a view controller for one of the split panes:

```
import Cocoa

class DayViewController: NSViewController {

    private var day: Day = Day()

    @IBOutlet weak var sleep: NSTextField!

    func set(day: Day){
        self.day = day
        //update()
    }

//    func update(){
        //sleep.doubleValue = day.sleep
  //  }   
}
```

I want to set the Day in the app delegate so that it displays it.

How do I get the instance of DayViewController in AppDelegate so I can set this value ?

Comment: why don't you do that inside the viewDidLoad method of DayViewController itself?

Comment: I was trying to keep my model code separate from the ViewController. This is just a simple case but ultimately the Day being view will change and I felt that should be managed outside of the view controller. I'm new to SWIFT so perhaps I thinking about this the wrong way. I will do this and see where it leads as the app grows !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing. Thought it may be of interest. Still undecided as to whether this is a hack or not.

In DayViewController I set a reference to it in the AppDelegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let app: AppDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    app.dayViewController = self
}
```

In AppDelegate I can then set the day for the view:

```
var dayViewController: DayViewController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let day: Day = Day.init(date: Date(), sleep: 9.5)
    dayViewController!.set(day: day)
}
```

Comment: This is spaghetti code. What's wrong with doing self.day = Day.init(date: Date(), sleep: 9.5) in viewDidLoad of your view controller?

Comment: Ultimately the Day won't be initialised there. I will have a model which will have multiple Days in it. As the day changes I will want to update the view.  It felt wrong to put modelling code in the ViewController. I agree this doesn't feel right either. Be create to see a best practise of MVC in SWIFT.

Comment: Right about spaghetti code... now don't have this. Think it was just a matter of getting a little more experience with SWIFT

Comment: @StevenLord Can you elaborate on how you would write this now that you are more experienced with Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
    if  window?.rootViewController is DayViewController {
        guard let dayVC =  window?.rootViewController as? DayViewController else {
            //there was an error
            return
        dayVC.set(day: new Day())
    }
```

I'm not sure if it will work. Maybe it is better to do the way @Siyavash said... put in the viewDidLoad itself.

Comment: I tried something similar to this as it had been suggested in older posts but it doesn't appear to work in Xcode 9 and SWIFT 4 - in the App Delegate I can't get a handle on window.

Comment: yep I had tried that. My searches had suggested thats the answer. It seems in Xcode 9 (SWIFT 4) App Delegate doesn't have a reference to the window. I thought I was missing something and there was some other method to get it but couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe its a Swift 4 thing, I don't really know. But here in my projects I set a var window: UIWindow? and i use o if let window = self.window. It works here

Answer (score 0):

As requested in a comment here’s what I do now I have more experience of swift.

The example used a simple “Day” class as my model but in my implementation the model is called “TrainingDiary”. I now have virtually nothing in my AppDelegate. Instead I did the following:

1. I have protocol which all the view controllers that provide a view on the model implement

   ```
   protocol TrainingDiaryViewController{
       func set(trainingDiary td: TrainingDiary)
   }
   ```
2. I have my view controller for the main window which now has a TabViewController in it (rather than the split view I had but this approach would work for that).
3. In that view controller I have overridden prepare(for:sender:):

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

       guard let tabViewController = segue.destinationController as? NSTabViewController else {return}

       for controller in tabViewController.childViewControllers{
           if let c = controller as? TrainingDiaryViewController{
               trainingDiaryVCs.append(c)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This means I now have a reference to all view controllers that are views on a TrainingDiary
4. In the main view there is a TableView which I use to manage the training diaries (i.e. add, remove, select). The main view controller is set as the TableViews delegate and the TableView is set in IB to have single selection and to avoid no selection. I then implemented:

   ```
   func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
       if let trainingDiary = trainingDiarysArrayController.selectedObjects[0] as? TrainingDiary{

           for c in trainingDiaryVCs{
               c.set(trainingDiary: trainingDiary)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

All works great.